# Creating a server for user Internet orders

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, session, redis

I've been learning the basics of node over the last couple of days and finally hooked up what I needed.  I'm just after someone to comment on if I have gone the right way around this task.

It creates a server which users access to get updates to Orders through server side events.
The events are published through redis which I subscribe to the queue.

```
var redis = require('redis'),
    http = require('http'),
    os = require("os"),
    PHPUnserialize = require('php-unserialize');

function sendServerSendEventForInternetOrders(req, res) {
    req.socket.setTimeout(0); // let request last as long as possible
    var hostname;
    if(os.hostname() == "kipos"){
        hostname = os.hostname()+".dev";
    }else{
        hostname = os.hostname();
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://'+hostname
    });

    res.write('\n');

    var phpSession = req.url.match('\/internetOrders\/(.*)')[1];

    console.log(phpSession + " - created client");
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    // In case we encounter an error...print it out to the console
    redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log(phpSession + " - Redis Error: " + err);
    });

    var phpSession = req.url.match('\/internetOrders\/(.*)')[1];

    var taID;
    var takeaway;

    redisClient.get("PHPREDIS_SESSION:" + phpSession, function (err, reply) {
        if (reply != null || err != null) {
            taID = PHPUnserialize.unserializeSession(reply).LoggedIn.TaID;
            console.log(phpSession + " - " + taID);
            startSub();
        } else {
            res.end();
            console.log(phpSession + " - exit");
        }
    });
    function startSub() {
        redisClient.select(1, function () {
            redisClient.get(taID + "T", function (err, reply) {
                if (reply == null) {
                    res.end();
                    console.log(phpSession + " - exit");
                    return;
                }
                takeaway = JSON.parse(reply);
                console.log(phpSession + " - "+takeaway.TaWebName);
            });

            redisClient.subscribe(taID + "IOU");

            // When we receive a message from the redis connection
            redisClient.on("message", function (channel, message) {
                sendMessage(message);
            });

            req.on("close", function () {
                redisClient.unsubscribe();
                redisClient.quit();
                console.log(phpSession + " - exit");
            });
        });
    }
    function sendMessage(data){
        res.write("data: " + data + '\n\n'); // Note the extra newline
        console.log(phpSession + " - data: " + data);
    }
};

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.url);
    if (req.headers.accept && req.headers.accept == 'text/event-stream') {
        if (req.url.match('\/internetOrders\/(.*)')) {
            sendServerSendEventForInternetOrders(req, res);
        }
        else if (req.url == '/windowsApp') {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end();
        }
        else {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end();
        }
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end("Hello Kipos!"); // Kept this in for checking node server is up!
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing that you could change is the way that this if else statement is written

```
var hostname;
if(os.hostname() == "kipos"){
    hostname = os.hostname()+".dev";
}else{
    hostname = os.hostname();
}
```

Here you are deciding what a variables value should be using an if/else statement, this is a good spot to use a JavaScript ternary operator.

Example Ternary Statement:

```
var variableName = red == blue ? trueValueAssignment : falseValueAssignment;
```

so your code would look like this

```
var hostname = os.hostname() == "kipos" ? os.hostname() + ".dev" : os.hostname();
```